# Changing modelstate using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jquery function. From that I want to change my ModelState state property into InValid. Is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, this is done on the server side, OR assign a regular expression [DataAnnotation] to that value so you can change it on the client side so the server side thinks its invalid. This is best done in your controller method anyways - as javascript from a validation standpoint can easily be forged.

Comment: in your controller's action method you would have something like:    if(someValidationFails){ ModelState.AddError("fieldname", "error message here");}